# Reassign variable name/ label

Tags: r, label, hmisc

Sample data code

```
    library(Hmisc)
data = data.frame(var=c("one", "two", "three"), outcome = c(5, 12, 4))
data$v1 <- factor(data$var,
                    levels = c("one", "two", "three"),
                    labels = c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

So this works to add labels to the variables however is there a better way that will be less likely to user error? For example, how can I do this where I say :

```
"one" = "red", "two" = "blue" ?
```